# Using Sencha 6.5.3, how may I configure a panel such that hideOnMaskTap is true and transparent is true?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

Using Sencha 6.5.3, how may I configure a panel such that `hideOnMaskTap` is true and `transparent` is true?

I found this for a transparent mask:

```
modal: {
  transparent: true
}
```

---

This is how I create the panel:

```
Ext.create({
        xtype: 'panel',
        cls: 'o-searcher-results',
        hideOnMaskTap: true,
        modal: {
            transparent: true
        },
        minHeight: '30%',
        maxHeight: '500px',
        scrollable: true,
        hidden: true
}));
```

but it doesn't work.

[This is the sencha fiddle.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hpk)

I'm using Sencha 6.5.3 modern and Sencha Cmd 6.5.3.6

Comment: There aren't any hooks that let you control the styling of the mask. Modal is a boolean value and the mask creation code is buried in the middle of a method.

Comment: I thought they had..

Comment: I don't know why but It's really working on certain cases with this
`modal: {
  transparent: true
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you could do it, first create a class for your mask:

```
.modal_mask{
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

Then add those listeners to the panel to modify temporarily the mask class

```
var mymask;
var panel = Ext.create({
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Floated',
    html: 'context panel text',
    anchor: true,
    modal: true,
    hideOnMaskTap: true,
    listeners: {
        show: function(win) {

           //Find the mask    
           var dom = Ext.dom.Query.select('.x-mask');

           //store it (search again on hide event doesn't work, don't know why)
           mymask = Ext.get(dom[0]);

           //add a new class
           mymask.addCls('modal_mask');

        },
        hide:  function(win) {

            //Remove the class you just add
            mymask.removeCls('modal_mask');
        }
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Note there may be multiple masks, so querying for everything may not be appropriate depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.